# How to allow suscriber to access specific pages in dashboard?

Tags: user-roles, admin-menu, dashboard

I want to create some pages in admin dashboard which are also shown to subscribers. Normally subscriber can see dashboard page and profile only. I want to create a page called Orders and show to subscribers. But not other pages.

How can I do ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, you can add a menu (or an admin) page using:

- [`add_menu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/) to add a top-level menu page
- [`add_submenu_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/) to add a submenu page

And there are also helper/wrapper functions you can use for adding a submenu page to the standard WordPress menu pages such as [`add_users_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_users_page/) for the Users/Profile page. You can check the other available helper functions on the Related → Used By section on [this page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_submenu_page/#related).

All those functions have a `$capability` parameter which is the minimum user/role capability required to view/access the menu page (and link). So you can use that parameter to restrict the menu page to certain users.

Here's an example for your case, where the role is `subscriber` which has the capability `read`:

```
function my_add_orders_menu_page() {
    add_menu_page(
        'Orders',             // Page title.
        'Orders',             // Menu title.
        'read',               // Capability.
        'my-orders',          // Menu slug.
        'my_orders_menu_page' // The callback that renders the menu page.
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_add_orders_menu_page' );

function my_orders_menu_page() {
    echo 'Yay, it works!';
}
```

Note: You should read the note about `option_page_capability_{$option_group}` on [this page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_menu_page/#notes).